# Is the solution wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Using cylindrical coordinates, calculate $$ \int_0^2dx\int_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dy\int_0^a zdz \quad (a>0).$$

I found that $0 \le r \le 1, 0 \le z \le a, 0 \le \theta \le \pi$.

Thus $$ \int_0^{\pi}d\theta\int_0^a zdz\int_0^1r^2dr = \frac{a^2\pi}{6}.$$

I thought I had finally found a correct solution to a question regarding multiple integrals (because I'm not really good at it...), but apparently the answer should be $\frac89a^2$.

How come I'm so off? I find it very suspicious that there is no $\pi$ in the final answer.

What is the correct answer?

Comment: The $r$ limits are not correct since $0\leq y \leq \sqrt{2x-x^2}$ which is not the unit circle

Comment: Isn't the radius of the circle just $1$?

Comment: $y^2=2x-x^2\rightarrow (x-1)^2+y^2=1$ note $r$ is the radius centered at the origin not $(1,0) $ same thing will be for $\theta$

Comment: You have the upper semi circle whose center is (1,0) and have radius 1, or you can translate your semicircle with your limits

Comment: See the domain in the $xy$-plane [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tp7f5aobrn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the semicircle in question is centered not at the origin, but at $(1,0).$ Thus, your upper $r$ limit is incorrect, as is your upper $\theta$ limit. Consider:

[image]

Note that the upper limit for $r$ varies as $\theta$ does, and that $\theta$ varies only to $\frac\pi 2.$ To find the upper limit for $r,$ we use the pythagorean formula: $$r^2=x^2+y^2=x^2+2x-x^2=2x,$$ so since $x=r\cos\theta,$ then we have $$r^2=2r\cos\theta,$$ whence $r=2\cos\theta$ is the upper limit. Thus, our triple integral will instead be $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\int_0^arzr\,dz\,dr\,d\theta=\int_0^az\,dz\cdot\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}r^2\,dr\,d\theta.$$